# ros2: command not found

Tags: ros

I'm trying to run ros2 iron irwini on Ubuntu 22.04.1 by using the ros2 documentation guide for ubuntu.
I source the setup file like this: `. ~/ros2_iron/install/local_setup.bash` and then run a test program `ros2 run demo_nodes_cpp talker`. I keep getting `ros2: command not found` as a result. I have tried reinstalling ros2, and change `local_setup.bash` to `local_setup.sh` and `local_setup.zsh` but to no avail. Does anyone know what else I can try or what I'm doing wrong here?
Thank you.